# combining a multi_match and a geo_bounding_box query in elasticSearch not returning results

Tags: elasticsearch, geocoding

I'm writing an `elasticSearch` *query* against an index that contains **lat/long**. It is indexed as correct type to work with `geoSpatial` *queries*.

I am trying to aggregate places based on the current bounding box in a mapbox map and getting the bounds. The map also has a search box where user search with some string. Combining both the search and `geoBounding`, I am forming the following *query*.

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":100,
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "sort":[
      {
         "place_name.keyword":"asc"
      }
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
              "multi_match":{
               "query":"w",
               "fields":[
                  "place_name^3",
                  "properties.top_category",
                  "properties.brands"
               ],
               "operator":"and"
            }
          },
         {
            "geo_bounding_box":{
               "location.point":{
                  "top_right":{
                     "lat":38.89450183333278,
                     "lon":-90.38570942514077
                  },
                  "bottom_left":{
                     "lat":38.88102629071099,
                     "lon":-90.40970118570218
                  }
               }
            }
         }
       ]
      }
   }
}
```

But the query returns 0 hits.

**When I run just the multi_match separately and the geo_bounding_box separately both returns the results as expected. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here.**

I tried this as well using one as a filter

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":100,
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "sort":[
      {
         "place_name.keyword":"asc"
      }
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":
            {
              "multi_match":{
               "query":"W",
               "fields":[
                  "place_name^3",
                  "properties.top_category",
                  "properties.brands"
               ],
               "operator":"and"
            }
            },
         "filter":{
            "geo_bounding_box":{
               "location.point":{
                  "top_right":{
                     "lat":38.89450183333278,
                     "lon":-90.38570942514077
                  },
                  "bottom_left":{
                     "lat":38.88102629071099,
                     "lon":-90.40970118570218
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Getting same issue. I know the data exists because calling with only the geo_bounding_box returns this data. But not when I combine it with a multi_match, the data should match because the place name matches.
[image]

Update: Added the index mapping

```
{
  "places_here_integration" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "location" : {
          "properties" : {
            "DMA_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "DMA_name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "county_id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "county_name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "geo_point" : {
              "type" : "geo_point",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "point" : {
              "type" : "geo_shape"
            },
            "polygon" : {
              "type" : "geo_shape"
            },
            "state_name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "state_usps" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "place_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "properties" : {
          "properties" : {
            "address" : {
              "properties" : {
                "city" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "region" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "state" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "street_address" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "zip_code" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "brands" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "created_datetime" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "created_user" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ids" : {
              "properties" : {
                "building_id" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "parkingarea_id" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "place_id" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "related_place_ids" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "tenantspace_id" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "naics_code" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "operating_information" : {
              "properties" : {
                "operating_hours" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "fri" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "close" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "open" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "mon" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "close" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "open" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "sat" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "close" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "open" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "sun" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "close" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "open" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "thu" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "close" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "open" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "tue" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "close" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "open" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "wed" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "close" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "open" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "operating_hours_note" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "phone_number" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "place_category_name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "sub_category" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "top_category" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your index mapping please?

Comment: @Val Updated the question with index mapping

Comment: Ok, then it's not possible that `w` or `W` match `Wilkie` with a multi_match query, i.e. `place_name`, `brands` and `top_category` are all analyzed by a standard analyzer.

Comment: @Val Can you please pardon my ignorance and tell me what else I can do to combine these two?

Comment: What I'm saying is that given your mapping, it's impossible that you were able to match `w` or `W` using a multi_match query on place_name as you stated in your question (i.e. `When I run just the multi_match separately... both returns the results as expected`)

Comment: But I can get results when I just run the multi_match query alone with the same query "W"